# I have a piece of data that can be a number from 1 to 7. How many of these can I compress into a single byte and how?

Tags: algorithm, numbers, compression

As a single byte can hold up to 256 values it should be possible to uniquely map more than one value per byte. I am however unsure about how many I can store without loss.

Is there a generalized algorithm to do this if I have a specific range of values I need to cover?

Can I improve the mapping if I map to a larger wordsize?

And idealized answer would be an algorithm to map x (independent) ranges of size n to m bits.

Comment: I'm not sure why you've tagged this question with c++.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I meant it can store one integer of range 0 to 255. So if we reduce the range we should be able to increase storage capacity.

Comment: This has many potential solutions. Without knowing more its impossible to give the maximum compression. You have 7 values which is less than a power of 2. Simple suggestions would therefore be a little redundant. How you reduce that redundancy can be quite complex and would likely vary according to the nature of the actual data. Are some values more frequent than others for example?

Comment: The idea is using this in a lookup-table for moves to take in a game (Connect-4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the most general terms, when you have a value that goes from 1 to 7 (I'm assuming inclusive,) which is equivalent of the range [0..6], you can
think of it as a digit in **base 7**.

This means that a string of them forms a number in base 7. Then, the easiest thing you can do is to store that number in a computer variable (in effect, turning it into base 2, but you don't usually have to think about that, since a number is a number.)

Now lets do some calculations about how many of your values will fit in how many bits. Obviously, one value will fit in 3 bits (and you will waste 1 out of 8 values, or 12.5% of the 3 bits.)
Two values - which is equivalent to a two-digit number in base 7 - will have a range of 0 to 48, and will fit in 6 whole bits (and will waste 15 out of 64 binary values, or 23.4%.)
Three values will have a range of 0 to 342, and will fit in 9 whole bits and waste a lot of values.

I think you can figure out the rest. Note that the actual (fractional) number of bits required to store each number (in this case 7) is by definition its *logarithm* in base 2.

To actually encode and decode in such a way, you just need to successively multiply by 7 (encode) or divide by 7 (decode) the same what that you would convert numbers into any other bases. For example, if your values are `x`, `y`, and `z`, the following will hold:

```
// x,y,z must be in [0..6], so probably have to subtract 1 from each first...
// then:
encoded = x * 1 + y * 7 + z * 49;  // encoded will fit in 9 bits.

decoded_x = (encoded /  1) % 7;     // also need a plus one.
decoded_y = (encoded /  7) % 7;     // same
decoded_z = (encoded / 49) % 7;     // ditto
```

In general, to map and pack any number of values, each in the range [0..m-1] into a number of bits, you do the same thing as above. Think of each of your values as a single digit in a (possibly large) number in **base `m`**, and then store that number in any variable that can hold it.

**Note 1**: Usually, you get less wasted bits the more values you pack into a single number. For example, some comments and other answers suggest packing each base-7 value into 3 bits. If you do that, you can only store 10 of them in a 32-bit variable. But you can actually pack 11 (whole) values in 32 bits. Admittedly, storing 1 value per 3 bits is faster to encode and decode (using only shifts and masking,) which makes the choice dependent on your needs.

**Note 2**: There are ways to talk about (and reason about) *fractional* bit counts. For example, each base-7 digit will take up 2.81 bits. And there are other ways to encode and store them as a collection. But that's a more complex matter in the realm of coding and compression. If you are curious, you can read about "arithmetic coding".

**Note 3**: Talking about compression, there are *far* better ways to pack several values into a number of bits, *if you know more about them*. That is, if some of them are more likely to be specific values, or equal to each other, or whatever. Also, if there is a large enough number of values, you can extract these relationships from the data itself. This is - in essense - what a general purpose lossless compressor does.

**Note 4**: Keep in mind that you can even do this kind of encode and decode (the way I've suggested) if the ranges of your values aren't the same. For example, if `x` and `z` are in the range [0..6], but `y` is in [0..4], then you can encode and decode them like this:

```
encoded = x * 1 + y * 7 + z * (7 * 5);  // encoded will fit in 8 bits now!

decoded_x = (encoded /  1) % 7;
decoded_y = (encoded /  7) % 5;
decoded_z = (encoded / 35) % 7;
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining this in detail. This is supposed to be used in a LUT. At the moment I do not know how the data will look exactly, but your pointers to various ways of compression will help with analyzing in the correct way. The LUT is supposed to store the next best possible move for a given board configuration in a game of connect-4.

Comment: @ValentinMetz, were I you, I would go and accept Mark Adler's answer. He is Mark Adler, after all!

Answer (score 3):

*n* symbols that are equally probable will take *lg n* bits, where *lg* is the logarithm base 2. You can store *floor(m / lg n)* of those in *m* bits, encoding them into the *m* bits as digits of a base *n* integer.

For *n=7* and *m=8*, you can store *2*. Generally you would want to pick an *m* that makes the number of unused bits small. *m=48* (six bytes) is a good choice here, in which you can store *17* symbols. *7<sup>17</sup>=232,630,513,987,207*, which is close to but less than *2<sup>48</sup>=281,474,976,710,656*. Only about a quarter of a bit is wasted, or about half a percent of the 48 bits. Also the base conversions can be done efficiently with 64-bit arithmetic.

Comment: @ValentinMetz If I were you, I would leave my accept on yzt's answer, since it is more descriptive and instructive.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i totally misunderstand you, but a byte contains 8 bits. Every bit can be zero or one. Now one byte can be in 256 different states respectively can hold a number as large as 255 at max. To represent a number between 1 to 7 (or 0 to 6) you need three bits. Like 001 = 1; 010 = 2; 011 = 3 ... and so on. So normally you can store to two numbers between 1 to 7 in one byte. But then you are wasting two bits. Maybe you can use overlapping bytes. In three bytes you can store 8 values and you would not waste any bit. Maybe you can think of some fancy algorithm to store three values in one byte with some restriction. For example if you know that at least one value is not identical to the others, you can try to sort the values within the byte. You think of a imaginary nineth bit. If the first value is smaller than the second it is one otherwise it is 0. But to go deeper on this some extra information on the data and the use case would be super.